# Collapse an array of objects on a property value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, lodash, reduce

How do I aggregate an array of objects on an object property in order to turn:

```
[ { key: 'black', value: [ '2', '3', '9' ] },
  { key: 'black', value: [ '1' ] },
  { key: 'gold', value: [ '2', '3' ] },
  { key: 'gold', value: [ '1' ] },
  { key: 'red', value: [ '9' ] },
  { key: 'white', value: [ '2', '3' ] },
  { key: 'white', value: [ '1' ] } ]
```

...into:

```
[ { key: 'black', value: [ '1', '2', '3', '9' ] },
  { key: 'gold', value: [ '1', '2', '3' ] },
  { key: 'red', value: [ '9' ] },
  { key: 'white', value: [ '1', '2', '3' ] } ]
```

...with javascript?

I feel like there should be a fairly straightforward way to do this with lodash or Array.reduce, but I cant for the life of me work out how to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const dedupe = a => [...new Set(a)].sort()

const arr = [
  { key: 'black', value: ['2', '3', '9', '1'] },
  { key: 'black', value: ['1'] },
  { key: 'gold', value: ['2', '3'] },
  { key: 'gold', value: ['1'] },
  { key: 'red', value: ['9'] },
  { key: 'white', value: ['3', '2'] },
  { key: 'white', value: ['1'] }
]

dedupe(arr.map(item => item.key)) // get unique, sorted array of 'key's
  .map(key =>
    arr
      .filter(item => item.key == key) // process each key in turn
      .reduce((a, c) => ({
        key,
        value: dedupe([...c.value, ...a.value]) // aggregate and sort the 'value's for each 'key'
      }))
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a temporary object for referencing the groups and return an array with the result in a single loop.

```js
var array = [{ key: 'black', value: ['2', '3', '9'] }, { key: 'black', value: ['1'] }, { key: 'gold', value: ['2', '3'] }, { key: 'gold', value: ['1'] }, { key: 'red', value: ['9'] }, { key: 'white', value: ['2', '3'] }, { key: 'white', value: ['1'] }],
    result = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.key]) {
        this[a.key] = { key: a.key, value: [] };
        result.push(this[a.key]);
    }
    this[a.key].value = this[a.key].value.concat(a.value);
    this[a.key].value.sort();
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `this` should be referring to the `window` context.

Comment: @ryeballar, no, its [`thisArgs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Using_thisArg) of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). the content is an empty object `{}`.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group first in an map and then produce the output you want

```
var output = {};
obj.forEach(function(val){
 output[val.key] = output[val.key] || [];
 output[val.key] = output[val.key].concat(val.value);
});
```

Now product the compressed output

```
var finalOutput = Object.keys(output).map(function(val){
      return { key: val, value: output[val] };
});
```

DEMO

```js
var obj = [{
  key: 'black',
  value: ['2', '3', '9']
}, {
  key: 'black',
  value: ['1']
}, {
  key: 'gold',
  value: ['2', '3']
}, {
  key: 'gold',
  value: ['1']
}, {
  key: 'red',
  value: ['9']
}, {
  key: 'white',
  value: ['2', '3']
}, {
  key: 'white',
  value: ['1']
}];

var output = {};
obj.forEach(function(val) {
  var key = val.key;
  var value = val.value;
  output[key] = output[key] || [];
  output[key] = output[key].concat(val.value);
});

var finalOutput = Object.keys(output).map(function(val) {
  return {
    key: val,
    value: output[val]
  };
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(finalOutput,0,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pretty easily write this yourself without any 3rd-party stuff:

```
var input = ...
var reduced = [];
var reducedMap = {};

input.forEach(function(obj) {
  if(!reduced.hasOwnProperty(obj.key) {
    reduced[obj.key] = [];
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < obj.value.length; i++) {
    if(reduced[obj.key].indexOf(obj.value[i]) < 0) {
      reduced[obj.key].push(obj.value[i]);
    }
  }
});

reduced = Object.keys(reducedMap).map(function(key){
  return {
    key: key,
    value: reducedMap[key].sort()
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `groupBy`, `map`, and `reduce` to create the desired result:

```
  var result = 
      _(input)
          .groupBy('key')
          .map(function(d, key) {
              return {
                  key: key, 
                  value: _.reduce(d, function(a, dd) {
                      return a.concat(dd.value);
                  }, []).sort(),
              };
          })
          .value();
```

Fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dw1zzfqt/1/

**ES2015 Version**

```
var result = 
    _(input)
        .groupBy('key')
        .map((d, key) => ({
            key, 
            value: _.reduce(d, (a, dd) => a.concat(dd.value), []).sort()
        }))
        .value();
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dw1zzfqt/2/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [{ key: 'black', value: ['2', '3', '9'] }, { key: 'black', value: ['1'] }, { key: 'gold', value: ['2', '3'] }, { key: 'gold', value: ['1'] }, { key: 'red', value: ['9'] }, { key: 'white', value: ['2', '3'] }, { key: 'white', value: ['1'] }],
    result = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.key]) {
        this[a.key] = { key: a.key, value: [] };
        result.push(this[a.key]);
    }
    this[a.key].value = this[a.key].value.concat(a.value);
    this[a.key].value.sort();
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash, as indicated by your question's tags:

```js
const arr = [ { key: 'black', value: [ '2', '3', '9' ] },
      { key: 'black', value: [ '1' ] },
      { key: 'gold', value: [ '2', '3' ] },
      { key: 'gold', value: [ '1' ] },
      { key: 'red', value: [ '9' ] },
      { key: 'white', value: [ '2', '3' ] },
      { key: 'white', value: [ '1' ] } ];
      
    const newArr = _.chain(arr) // Lodash<number, { key, value }>
        .groupBy("key") // Lodash<key, { key, value }>
        .mapValues(items => {
            return _.chain(items) // Lodash<number, value>
                .reduce((values, item) => [...values, ...item.value], []) // Lodash<number, value>
                .sortBy(_.identity)
                .sortedUniq()
                .value(); // value
        }) // Lodash<key, value>
        .map((value, key) => ({ key, value }))  // Lodash<number, { key, value }>
        .value(); // { key, value }[]
    
    console.log({ arr, newArr });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

We use `_.chain` to create a chain of transformations, and `_.value` to unwrap that chain into the computed result.